# C++ dynamic_cast exception

Tags: c++, exception, inheritance, virtual, dynamic-cast

Please help me to understand strange behavior:

I use dynamic_cast from `MyObject` to `MyLogicObject` when a destructor `~MyLogicObject()` in processing, but compiler throw an exception: `non_rtti_object`.

I'm sure that object `MyObject` is a polymorph type. Where am I wrong?

```
#ifndef MYOBJECT_H
#define MYOBJECT_H

#include <string>

class A
{
    int a;
};

class B
{
    int b;
};

class MyObject: public A,
                public B// if comment this row, and don't use multi inheritable, everything will be fine
{
    private: std::string name;
    private: bool singleshot;


    public: MyObject(void);

    public: virtual ~MyObject(void);

    protected: void Destroying(void);

    public: std::string GetName(void);

    public: virtual bool Rename(std::string _newName);
};

#endif

#include "MyObject.h"
#include "MyLogicObject.h"

MyObject::MyObject(void): singleshot(true)
{}


MyObject::~MyObject(void)
{
    printf("\n~my object\n");
    Destroying();
}


void MyObject::Destroying(void)
{
    if(singleshot)
    { 
        printf("\nexception!\n");
        dynamic_cast<MyLogicObject*>(this);// exception: non_rtti_object
        singleshot = false;
    }
}


std::string MyObject::GetName(void)
{
    return name;
}


bool MyObject::Rename(std::string _newName)
{
    name = _newName;
    return true;
}


#ifndef MYLOGICOBJECT_H
#define MYLOGICOBJECT_H
#include "MyObject.h"

    class MyLogicObject: public virtual MyObject // if not use virtual  inheritance (instead, use the standard inheritance), everything will be fine
    {
        public: MyLogicObject(void);

        public: virtual ~MyLogicObject(void);

        public: virtual void Update(float _delta = 0.0f);

        // if reimplement virtual method of base class, everything will be fine
        /*
        public: virtual bool Rename(std::string _newName)
        {
            return MyObject::Rename(_newName);
        }
        */ 
    };

    #endif 

#include "MyLogicObject.h"


MyLogicObject::MyLogicObject(void)
{}


MyLogicObject::~MyLogicObject(void)
{
    printf("\n~my logic object\n");
    Destroying();
}



void MyLogicObject::Update(float _delta)
{}

#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "MyLogicScene.h"


class C
{
    int c;
};



class DerivedObject: public MyLogicObject,
                     public C// if comment this row, and don't use multi inheritable, everything will be fine
{
    public: DerivedObject(void)
    {}

    public: virtual ~DerivedObject(void)
    {
        printf("~derived object: %s\n", GetName().c_str());
        //Destroying(); // if call Destroying in this place, overything will be file
    }
};


int main()
{
    DerivedObject* object1 = new DerivedObject();
    object1->Rename("object1");

    printf("delete object1...\n");
    delete object1;


    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From inside the destructor MyObject have already destroyed the MyLogicObject part of the object.

Comment: "But I'm sure that object B is a polymorph type." `Class B { int b; };` is not polymorphic. It needs to have either defined or inherited at least one virtual method (e.g. virtual destructor) to be polymorphic. But in your example I think it doesn't matter whether B is polymorphic or not.

Comment: if you run my code you will see that the error occurs before the ~MyLogicObject is finished. It means that the MyLogicObject still exists. Also, why the code works fine if you remove the inheritance of the C class?

Comment: @Marian Spanik you right, it was my typo, I meant about the class MyObject

Comment: Could you post your output?

Comment: Your example [online](http://ideone.com/CShnni) seems to work. I did not dig through but the use of virtual functions is special during destruction. It is quite easy to mess something up.

Comment: @qPCR4vir Output: delete object1... ~derived object: object1  ~my logic object GOOD BYE

Comment: What is MyLogicScene.h?

Comment: @mkaes this is strange, i use vs C++ 2008 and get an exception

Comment: @qPCR4vir it does not effect, you can remove it

Comment: @ qPCR4vir "From inside the destructor MyObject have already destroyed the MyLogicObject part of the object. " - that part of code is not reached. It crashes when a destructor of **MyLogicObject** calls the Destroying on my computer in VC++2010. It is either a bug or an undefined behaviour (but I don't know why it shoud be undefined). But why the Destroying method is not a member of MyLogicObject and called only in ~MyLogicObject , when it requires that the this pointer is of type MyLogicObject?

Comment: It's annoying trying to test (or even read) your code because you've split it into lots of different files, which is completely unnecessary. There is no need for five separate files to demonstrate the problem (i.e. it is not a [**minimal**, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: @Marian Spanik maybe you right, but I still do not understand the cause of this exception

Comment: Please post code that can be compiled straight off your post.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to dynamic cast an object of a base class (MyObject) type to the derived class (MyLogicObject). And this conversion is not allowed with dynamic_cast unless the base class is polymorphic and rtti is enabled. See [this](http://www.codingunit.com/cplusplus-tutorial-typecasting-part-2-rtti-dynamic_cast-typeid-and-type_info) for reference.

So you basically need to enable rtti in your compiler options.
Once that is done make sure that object1 is a complete object of the derived class (MyLogicObject) for the cast to work without raising an exception.

It would work in the opposite scenario too. If you were trying for example to dynamic cast an object of a derived class (MyLogicObject) type to the base class (MyObject).

Comment: but my rtti option is enabled by default, i checked this in project->properties->C++->language tab. i find my problem: warning C4436: dynamic_cast from virtual base 'MyObject' to 'MyLogicObject' in constructor or destructor could fail with partially-constructed object   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155805.aspx

Comment: See the second paragraph: "make sure that object1 is a complete object of the derived class (MyLogicObject)".

Comment: It says the same thing with different words.

Comment: How can I know this at the time when the object1 is destroying? on gcc my code works fine, but not in vs 2008/2010

Comment: my problem seems to be explained. erroneous calculation of offset in dynamic_cast. this problem vs C++. if clearly implement the constructors and destructors that everything will be fine.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to fix it Gregory. If you found my answer somewhat helpful, please up vote it.